# How to control repet scrolling of sphere image in android

Tags: android, panoramas

I am using android panoramaGL,it is working fine 360 sphere and sensor rotation. But when you click on image and scroll some distance with out lifting finger on screen, it is scrolling continuously (my finger is not moving but it is scrolling). How to stop it?

I am using [panoramagl-android](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/) library.